# How to use port 5434 on main server for postgresql streaming replication

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, connection-refused

I am trying to do streaming replication between two postgresql servers. Main server is listening on port 5434 and I have to keep it so. When I run "pg_basebackup -h (main server ip) -D /var/lib/postgresql/13/main/ -U replicator -P -v -R -X stream -C -S slaveslot1" on replica server I get the follwing error:
"pg_basebackup: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused. Is the server running on host (main server ip) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"
Almost all similar questions that I found in the web are dealing with some other problems as their main server is already using port 5432.
So, could you please let me know how I can keep port 5434 on main server and still run the above command for replication? Thanks in advance!

I was expecting the command to run normally and ask me for password.
I have changed the port to 5432 and in that case it works, so the command itself doesn't have mistakes in it.
But I don't know what/how I can do it if I am keeping port 5434.

Comment: In case anybody faces the same problem in the future, I solved it by adding -p 5434 right after the ip address

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `-p` option of `pg_basebackup`, or you can set the `PGPORT` environment variable, or you can use the `-d` option with a connection string that contains `port=5434`.